# Determining If Rebuild was requested in Visual studio 2012 AfterClean task

Tags: visual-studio-2012, build-process

Anyone knows if i could determine if AfterClean task was executed in context of Rebuild.
I am only intrested to execute my task if Clean is executed explicitly from project context menu.

```
<Target Name="MyTask" AfterTargets="AfterClean">
   <Message Text="Removing file: cache.data" Importance="high" />
   <Exec Command="del /S cache.data" ></Exec>
</Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

found answer myself, there may be a better way.

```
<Target Name="BuildExecutedFlag"  BeforeTargets="BeforeRebuild" >
 <CreateProperty Value="1">
  <Output
      TaskParameter="Value"
      PropertyName="WasBuildExecuted" />
 </CreateProperty>
</Target>
 <Target Name="MyTask" AfterTargets="AfterClean" Condition="'$(WasBuildExecuted)' != '1'">
  <Message Text="Removing file: cache.data" Importance="high" />
  <Exec Command="del /S cache.data" ></Exec>
 </Target>
```